# Add Angular 4 Project to Visual Studio WITHOUT using ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio-2017

I was wondering if it was possible to add a Project to an existing Visual Studio 2017 Solution that runs Angular 4 but is not powered by ASP.NET Core 2.0.

At the moment we already have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 API project and we want to seperate the API and the Angular 4 Front end as two seperate projects within the same solution.

We tried using the Angular 4 template but found that we are just using asp.net core to serve up a single view which then runs the angular 4 code. I have tried just added an existing website but cannot find a way for that to run when hitting F5 in a way that is similar to running "ng serve" command.

Would someone be able to let me know if this is at all possible?

Thanks

Comment: did you get any answers ?

Comment: @N.K no i did not. In the end we just decided to build the project using the Angular CLI and edit it using Visual Studio code.

Comment: try using SystemJS ... i did some workarounds and it worked for me...